# Destroying all the previously created objects when the Game Start over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I am using `Destroy(gameObject)` for some gameobjects to pass them on another level. Now the problem is after my player dies there are objects left on the scene  when I restart the game after the player dies, I only want the objects that i created when the game started.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean `DontDestroy`?

Answer (score 0):

Store the player created gameObjects in a list, then call `Destroy()` on them after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need to destroy object that you marked with `DontDestroyOnLoad` you are doing something wrong.

Use it only on objects that you really want to keep across the scenes. If you need to make changes in these objects, just change parameters values and make other objects live only in scenes where they belong.